# Find active user

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using [mongoid](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid) gem for storing events and users.

My goal is to find most active user (has biggest number of events).

Is there more correct way find active user for last hour then given solution?

```
User has_many Events

hash = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = 0 }

Event.where(:created_at.gte => 1.hour.ago).each_with_object(hash) do |event, memo|
  memo[event.user_id] += 1
end.sort_by { |user_id,score| score }
```

Thanks

Comment: Just a comment.. You can initialize the hash by just doing this: ```hash = Hash.new(0)```

Comment: No, it won't work, because it need to be initialized but not just return the default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should let the database do the work for you by using aggregation framework to find this.

The pipeline would be something like:

```
db.events.aggregate({$match:{created_at:{$gt:<an-hour-ago>}}},
                    {$group:{_id:"$user_id", score:{$sum:1}}},
                    {$sort:{score:-1}}, {$limit:1} );
```